# What are the first steps to take to properly create a Facebook APP for a specific Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-page

Note: I wasn't sure if I should've added this to stackoverflow or the webmasters site. Let me know if I should have added to both or a specific one?

I am trying to implement elements of a Facebook Page for a non-profit organization into their website. However I am not sure if I am going about this the right way. All the information I find is vague on the area that I am completely lost in.

Details:

1. They have a Facebook "Page" for their organization.
2. I created a Facebook APP at: https://developers.facebook.com/apps (Right now all I did was created it.)
3. They added my facebook account as an Admin to their Page.
4. They have a domain, theirdomain.com but development is being done on my personal domain at dev.mydomain.com . (Their current host is very restrictive so once development is done I will move everything to their domain.com but on a different host.)
5. Don't think it is needed for this questions but I am in a LAMP environment.

My Questions:

1. How do I install the APP or link it with their Facebook page so it has access to their information? People keep saying to create a facebook app, but I am finding no exact information on how someone then goes about making that app work specifically for the Facebook Page.
2. Since they made me admin, now I get a bunch of emails from their Page updates and the Page is linked to my personal Facebook account. Is this how all developers go about things when creating facebook functionality for clients? I have a feeling that this is not the way I should have went about doing things....
3. Once I am done implementing the facebook functionality into their website, I no longer want access to the Facebook APP nor the Facebook Page. What would be the best way to pre-plan this so the transition is smooth?

My only purpose of creating the APP is because I want to display "Likes" and Photo Albums on their website. Maybe some other functionality but basically just displaying certain Facebook Page content onto their website.

I have been reading for days, but really confused. Once I am able to get pointed in the right direction I am sure it will all make sense, I just need that missing puzzle piece to click.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use this link

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&display=popup&next=APPS_SECURE_CANVAS_URL`

to add an app to a page.

Or this

```
http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=your_app_id&pages=1
```

should work too.

2) Yes, since you are now admin of page, you will receive pages updates like any other admin. You can choose to opt out of updates from settings page.
(or you can ask client to follow these steps)

3) You can remove yourself from page admin but if you can remove the app (or it will detach itself from the page). Better ask client to create an app. I ask client to create an app for them. This is the way to go.

**Edit (after comment)**

1) is the standard way to programmatically add apps to page.
To access facebook page photos, get an access token for page, and then via graph api (or by another method) fetch photos.

e.g.If your page has id '12345', 
`https://graph.facebook.com/12345/photos?access_token=<page_access_token>`
will grab the photos for you.

This would help `http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/`.

Comment: Thank you for answerinf #2 and #3, that makes sense. For #1, can I ask how you figured out that URL and just for verification what exactly does it do? I used it, and it added the APP into my facebook page, but is there anything else I would need to do to allow the APP access to the photo albums of the Facebook Page so I can display the photos of a FaceBook Page Photo Album on a website?